# Getting and error is store procedure

Tags: sql

I am getting this error:

```
  Msg 201, Level 16, State 4, Procedure NewEmployee, Line 0
    Procedure or function 'NewEmployee' expects parameter '@LastName', which was not supplied.
```

Here is my code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE NewEmployee (
     @LastName nvarchar(20)
     ,@FirstName nvarchar(10)
     ,@HireDate datetime
     ,@Birthdate datetime
     ,@Title nvarchar(30))

AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Employees (LastName,FirstName,HireDate,BirthDate,Title)
    VALUES (@LastName, @FirstName, @HireDate,@Birthdate,@Title)

End
GO
```

This is what I am trying to do.

I need to write a procedure to insert a new employee into the table with their last and first names, hire and birth dates, and job title.

I'm trying to add the following information by running the procedure:

```
Last Name: Beesley
First Name: Pam
Hire Date: Current Date
Birth Date: 12/30/1972
Title: Receptionist
Home Phone: 330-555-5555
```

Comment: Are you getting this error when you call the stored proc or when you try to create it?

Comment: What is your EXEC line looking like for executing the sproc?

Comment: Im not getting the error when i great it just when i try to run it.

Comment: Right. What are you executing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are not passing right number of parameters while exec the procedure can you share the exec statement ?

Comment: EXEC NewEmployee; I am woundering that i am suppose to be adding names to it and I should declar a return then exec the return?

Comment: EXEC NewEmployee 'MyLastName','MyFirstName',GETDATE(),GETDATE()-10000,'Title' should work

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work?

```
EXEC NewEmployee 'MyLastName','MyFirstName',GETDATE(),GETDATE()-10000,'My Title'
```

You can't just call that stored procedure after you create it. You have fields that you require. Oh, and your columns are sized entirely too small. Last name of 75 and First name of 50 in my opinion.